# PHP: Output name of array variable for use in one of its elements

Tags: php, arrays

In the code below, is there a way to get the name of the array from *within* that same array so it doesn't have to be typed multiple times?

```
$awesome_array = array(
    'fruit'=>'apple',
    'name'=>'awesome_array', // Name of array here
    'you_are_an'=>'awesome_array' // Name goes here too
);
```

That is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible directly. But you can achieve this behavior by defining the name prior to defining the array.

Here is 3 ways to do it. There can be more. But I cant recall any other way right now.

#### Array name is in a string

```
$array_name = 'awesome_array';
$$array_name = array(
    'fruit'=>'apple',
    'name'=>$array_name, // Name of array here
    'you_are_an'=>$array_name // Name goes here too
);
```

#### Most common way

Pekka reminded me in the comments.

```
$awesome_array = array('fruit'=>'apple');
$awesome_array['name'] = 'awesome_array';
$awesome_array['you_are_an'] = 'awesome_array';
```

#### Dynamically collect the name

```
$awesome_array = array('fruit'=>'apple');
// dynamically extracting the name of last defined variable
list($name) = array_slice(array_keys(get_defined_vars()), -1 , 1);
$awesome_array['name'] = $name;
$awesome_array['you_are_an'] = $name;
```

Comment: This is nice, but doing it on an entirely array basis instead of with variable variables would be nicer :)

Comment: Thats not possible as The variable is not yet defined.

Comment: I mean storing the array in an array itself `$my_array_container[$array_name] = array(....)`

Comment: @Pekka Yeah I agree. See my another new way. Pretty much dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_name = "awesome_array";
$$array_name = array(
    'fruit'=>'apple',
    'name'=> $array_name  // Name of array here
    'you_are_an'=>$array_name  // Name goes here too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but you can use variable variables:

```
$var = 'awesome_array';
$$var = array(
    'fruit'=>'apple',
    'name'=>$var, // Name of array here
    'you_are_an'=>$var // Name goes here too
);
```